# HAML View with header that introduces indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a problem with an email view that has a header which already adds some indentation. Here's the html code:

```
<p>
  <some elements in header>
  <p>
    Dear X
    <span>
      Actual content that changes
    <p>footer content
```

Now I'd like to split it into header and footer partials and use haml.

```
= render 'header'
      Actual content that changes # notice indentation larger than 2 spaces to keep the original spacing
    = render 'footer' # notice larger indentation, same as above
```

If I keep the original indentation, than it fails with errors like 'unexpected end-of-input' or improper indentation depending on if I add stuff like blocks `= succeed ... do` somewhere

If in contrast I just reset indentation in the main view file like this:

```
= render 'header'
  Actual content ...
= render 'footer' # seems weird as in the original view footer is inside header
```

I get errors `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

hmm, it seems like this approach is wrong and I can't just extract header because the header introduces indentation used by all other parts of the view (also footer), is that correct?

UPDATE: I also tried to add everything as block to first `render 'header' do everything else + render 'footer'` but for some reason I only saw header with empty content.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one, if I am not wrong you just wanted to render footer then your some contents and again render footer, correct me if wrong?

```
= render 'header'
%p 
    %span Actual content ...
    = render 'footer' # seems weird as in the original view footer is inside header
```

Comment: But both content and footer are indented inside header elements - footer partial doesn't contain closing tags obviously (haml). I ended up abandoning haml for this and switched to erb, then simple solution works:

    <%= render 'header' %>
    some content
    <%= render 'footer' %>

where header looks like <table><tr><td>somestuff.. and footer looks like 
...somestuff</td></tr></table>